# Convert bitmap to ImageSource give NullReference exception

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, stream, aforge

I've got WCF service to send image as a stream to client app.
My client app gets the stream :

```
 Stream imageStream = client.GetImage();
```

When I use this code:

```
imageStream.CopyTo(stream);
int size = (int)stream.Length;
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
BitmapFrame bf = BitmapFrame.Create(stream,
    BitmapCreateOptions.None,
    BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
cam_img.Source = bf;
```

It work's fine but I need apply some filters to image before assign to source.
So I need bitmap. First, I convert `Stream imageStream` to byte array and then I use some code I find on forums:

```
byte[] tab_img;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    imageStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    tab_img= memoryStream.ToArray();
}

Bitmap bm;
using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    mStream.Write (tab_img, 0, tab_img.Length);
    mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    bm = new Bitmap(mStream);

    Grayscale filter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
    Bitmap bm_post = filter.Apply(bm);

    ImageSourceConverter c = new ImageSourceConverter();


    object source = new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom(bm_post);
    ImageSource is1 = (ImageSource)source;
    cam_img.Source = is1;
}
```

but I still get `NullReferenceException` in line

```
object source = new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom(bm_post);
```

Comment: Not an answer, but shouldn't that line be `c.ConvertFrom(bm_post);`?

Comment: Also, can you add a breakpoint and check that `bm_post` is not null at that point.

Comment: @BrokenPixels no, its rest code from other function i implemented